# HTTPS Requests Ignoring Rewrite Rule

Tags: apache, ssl, url-rewriting, mamp

I have a simple rewrite rule in my .htaccess file that creates search engine friendly urls for my visitors. The rule works great over http connections, but for some reason when the request is made over https the rule is ignored.

Here is the contents of the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)/$ /$1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas or suggestions as to why https requests ignore the rule, but http requests acknowledge the rule? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I spent the entire day on Google and various forums to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think a `.php` isn’t search engine friendly?

Comment: You're right - .php is search engine friendly. I guess I was referring to what Tim Berners Lee said about cool URI's - http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your rule has nothing that depends on the port or protocol. My educated guess is that your HTTP and HTTPS sites are running under different settings: they are either using a different document root or the second does not [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#allowoverride) anything (it needs `All` or `FileInfo`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think you're right. I'm using MAMP (similar to WAMP for Windows/XAMPP for Linux). I'm not quite sure how they pre-configure SSL Vhosts. I'll do a little research and see if I can figure it out. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they're both served out of the same <Directory> stanza, compare the AllowOverride directive for the https <VirtualHost> to the non-ssl one.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It sounds like I need to look at my SSL vhost to fix this problem.